# Assistance To Rewrite Oracle SQL Query As Query Executed Without Stopping For A Long Time

Tags: sql, oracle

I would need assistance to rewrite the Oracle SQL Query below as the query executed without stopping for a long time. I have tried to rewrite the query using joins but the result is not what I wanted. Thank you.

```
SELECT ADDRESS_ID,
   ADDRESS,
   NETWORKCONVERAGE,
   ADDRESSBUILDINGTYPE,
   ADDRESSBUILDINGNAME,
   ADDRESSPOSTCODE,
   FTP_NAME,
   ORDER_ID_NEW,
   ORDER_STATUS,
   INSTALLATION_DATE
   
FROM (
    SELECT ADDRESSPOSTCODE || '_' || ADDRESSHOUSENUMBER || '_' || ADDRESSFLOORNUMBER || '_' || ADDRESSUNITNUMBER ADDRESS_ID,
           ADDRESSHOUSENUMBER || ' ' || ADDRESSSTREETNAME || ' #' || ADDRESSFLOORNUMBER || '-' || ADDRESSUNITNUMBER || ' Singapore ' || ADDRESSPOSTCODE ADDRESS,
           NETWORKCONVERAGE,
           ADDRESSBUILDINGTYPE,
           ADDRESSBUILDINGNAME,
           ADDRESSPOSTCODE,
           SUBSTR(FTPPORT, 1, INSTR(FTPPORT, '/', 1) - 1) FTP_NAME,
           ORDER_ID_NEW,
           FORM_STATUS ORDER_STATUS,
           TO_DATE(INSTALLATIONDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') INSTALLATION_DATE
    FROM ARADMIN4.ON_ADVANCEDINTERFACE_PORTALRES
    WHERE SUBSTR(ORDER_ID_NEW, 4, 2) = '01'
    AND SCHEDULE = '01'
)
WHERE ADDRESS_ID NOT IN (
                        SELECT (ADDRESSPOSTCODE || '_' || ADDRESSHOUSENUMBER || '_' || ADDRESSFLOORNUMBER || '_' || ADDRESSUNITNUMBER)
                        FROM ARADMIN4.ON_ADVANCEDINTERFACE_PORTALRES
                        WHERE SUBSTR(ORDER_ID_NEW, 4, 2) = '01'
                        AND SCHEDULE = '01'
                        AND FORM_STATUS = 'Completed'
                    );
```

I have tried to rewrite the query using join but the result is not what I wanted.

1 ADDRESS_ID might have few ORDER_ID with different ORDER_STATUS (Completed, Rejected, etc.). I would like to get the ADDRESS_ID where there is no ORDER_ID with ORDER_STATUS = 'Completed'.

For example, 01_01_01 have ORDER_ID_1 with Status = Completed and ORDER_ID_2 with Status = Rejected, 02_02_02 have ORDER_ID_1 with Status = Rejected and ORDER_ID_2 with Status = Pending, then when I run the SQL Query, it should return 02_02_02 only.

Answer (score 1):

Run the query with the following hint

```
SELECT /*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS * ADDRESS_ID,
   ADDRESS,
   NETWORKCONVERAGE,
   ADDRESSBUILDINGTYPE,
   ADDRESSBUILDINGNAME,
   ADDRESSPOSTCODE,
   FTP_NAME,
   ORDER_ID_NEW,
   ORDER_STATUS,
   ...
   ...
```

and then run

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'ALLSTATS LAST +COST'))
```

which will give an assessment of how the optimizer estimates differed from the actual numbers at each stage of execution.

Thats an excellent first step to tuning an SQL statement

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `NOT IN`, use an analytic function with conditional aggregation so that you can parse the data in a single table scan:

```sql
SELECT ADDRESS_ID,
       ADDRESS,
       NETWORKCONVERAGE,
       ADDRESSBUILDINGTYPE,
       ADDRESSBUILDINGNAME,
       ADDRESSPOSTCODE,
       FTP_NAME,
       ORDER_ID_NEW,
       ORDER_STATUS,
       INSTALLATION_DATE
FROM   (
  SELECT ADDRESSPOSTCODE || '_' || ADDRESSHOUSENUMBER || '_' || ADDRESSFLOORNUMBER || '_' || ADDRESSUNITNUMBER ADDRESS_ID,
         ADDRESSHOUSENUMBER || ' ' || ADDRESSSTREETNAME || ' #' || ADDRESSFLOORNUMBER || '-' || ADDRESSUNITNUMBER || ' Singapore ' || ADDRESSPOSTCODE ADDRESS,
         NETWORKCONVERAGE,
         ADDRESSBUILDINGTYPE,
         ADDRESSBUILDINGNAME,
         ADDRESSPOSTCODE,
         SUBSTR(FTPPORT, 1, INSTR(FTPPORT, '/', 1) - 1) as FTP_NAME,
         ORDER_ID_NEW,
         FORM_STATUS as ORDER_STATUS,
         INSTALLATIONDATE,
         COUNT(CASE form_status WHEN 'Completed' THEN 1 END) OVER (
           PARTITION BY address_id
         ) AS num_completed
  FROM   ARADMIN4.ON_ADVANCEDINTERFACE_PORTALRES
  WHERE  SUBSTR(ORDER_ID_NEW, 4, 2) = '01'
  AND    SCHEDULE = '01'
)
WHERE  num_completed = 0;
```

*Note: Never use `TO_DATE` on a column that is already a `DATE` data-type (which I assume `INSTALLATIONDATE` has). If your intention is to output the time component of the column as midnight then use `TRUNC` (rather than `TO_DATE`).*